# Component.GetComponent<T>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to get the Rigidbody component unity throws the error "Component.GetComponent()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context"
The code is as follows

```
 private void OnMouseUp()
{
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
    Vector2 directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * 100);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>.gravityScale = 1;
    
}
```

Comment: `GetComponent<T>` is a method. Your last line is missing parenthesis, it should be `GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().gravityScale = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is on this line:
`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>.gravityScale = 1;`

You want to call the method instead of just referring to it. Try this in its place:

`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 1;`

You could also consider only calling the function once and storing the Rigidbody2D in a variable, like so:

```
Rigidbody2D rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
rigidbody.AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * 100);
rigidbody.gravityScale = 1;
```